# How to take multiple input in a single line in python

Tags: python

I am using list comphrensions for this:

```
x = [i for i in int(raw_input("Enter Input:")).split(",")]
Enter Input : 1 2 3 4 5
```

But it throws the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "python", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1 2 3 4 5'
```

Can someone please sort it out.

Comment: Don't split with `','` , just split with a space.`....split()`. Moreover split will give you an array of values. You will have to iterate over each element and type cast to `int`.

Comment: I have just tried that, still not working

Comment: can u please upload the code

Comment: [int(i) for i in input().split()] this will by default split by space

Comment: kk got it thnx afaq

Comment: thnx @Rednivrug

Answer (score 1):

```
x = [int(i) for i in raw_input("Enter Input:").split(" ")]
```